# exception was thrown by the target of invocation” C# Httpclient

Tags: json.net, httpclient, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have two API created in .net core 3.1 (let us say API A & API B) API A will call API B and merging two outputs. But when call,
I am getting:

`Error:: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.: Error Executing C# Script`

The two APIs are running on different ports API A and API B.

I need to get the result from API A  to API B.so In my API A is a combination of API A and API B. I am using the same request for both.

The problem is when I call an external API call to API B from API B. But it works when I run API B only. I don't understand the issue

Code of the API B:

```cs
public async Task GetKeyData(string key){
    string dataKey = string.Empty;
    var requestUri = string.Format("{0}/{1}", _KeyUri, key);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { 
        UseDefaultCredentials = true
    });

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var rawData = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);

    // below  line are getting error when i call from api A to this 
    var jsonResponse = await rawData.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();  //error showing here
    string value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse);

    //balance code
    }
}
```

What mistake I am doing here?

Comment: The whole setup feels a bit odd, isn't there a different way to achieve this which would be more aligned with good coding practices?

Comment: What does `so In my API A is a combination of API A and API B.` mean?